# Prove that a certain intrinsic property of Turing machines is not decidable

Tags: computability, turing-machines

Can anyone help me to prove that the following language is nod decidable?

$$ A=\{\langle\,M,w,q\,\rangle\mid M \text{ is a $TM$ , $w$ is a word, $q$ is a state in $M$ and while $M$ runs on $w$ it visits the state $q$}\}$$

I can use rice theorem and reductions.

My intuition is that A is not decidable and I think we should prove it by assuming in contradiction that $A\in R$, hence there is $TM$ $S$ that decides $A$ and we can use it to build $TM$ $T$ that decides $A_{TM}$. contradiction to the fuct that $A_{TM}\notin R$.

any help will be apriciated!

Comment: What exactly does $A_{TM}$ mean to you?

Comment: Doesn't solving this trivially let you solve the Halting Problem? I think you can modify any Turing machine to have a single "halt" state.

Comment: @HenningMakholm A_{TM}=\{<M,w>|\text{$M$ accepts the word $w$}\}

Comment: @ThomasAndrews this is my try, is it ok?

assuming in contradiction that $A\in R$, hence there is $TM$ $S$ that decides $A$ and we can use it to build $TM$ $T$ that decides $HALT_{TM}$. 

where:

$T= \text{with input $<M,w>$}$
$\text{1. run $S$ on $<M,w,h>$ and if $S$ accepts $<M,w,h>$, accept $<M,w>$}.$
 
$\text{$h$ is halting state.}$

I am not sure if it is ok and why can I assume that there is only 1 halting state..

Comment: If there are more than one halting state, then select one of them to be _the_ halting state, and rewrite all the others to unconditionally do something arbitrary (write 1 and move right, or whatever) while jumping to _the_ halting state.

Comment: @HenningMakholm thanks.. just to be sure - the building of $T$ looks right to you?